# Forcing .NET application to use TLS 1.2 or later

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.2

I wonder how to force a .NET application targeting .NET Framework 4.8 to use TLS 1.2 or later (including future TLS versions).

The application execute as a Windows service. For >98% of the users, it is correctly using TLS 1.2 but in a couple of cases it tries to use older versions like TLS 1.0 or even SSL 3.0. The users who have had issues with it using older TLS versions has been able to resolve it by making registry changes, but telling users to reconfigure settings in Windows registry is a bit risky.

I have followed Microsofts recommendation to not hardcoded the application to use a specific TLS version and instead just rely on the OS default (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls).

So what I wonder is: Is there some way in a .NET application to:

1. Use the Windows default TLS version if it's TLS 1.2 or later.
2. If the Windows default TLS version is SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 then use TLS 1.2 or later (including TLS 1.3)

I know I can hardcode the TLS version using `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, but this goes against Microsofts recommendation and if I hardcode it to TLS 1.2 and 1.3, then whenever TLS 1.4 is used and the customers OS is patched to support it, my application will still use TLS 1.3 which I don't want.

Comment: .Net framework 4.8  depends on OS capabilities. Hardcoding this setting will probably break the application if the OS does not support the version (AFAIK). I'm afraid there isn't much you will be able to do. Except specifying a minimum required TLS version the OS has to support (due to server restrictions). It's the same message you are seeing now on the azure/devops platform about TLS. What kind of registry changes did they make?

Answer (score 1):

What about adding TLS declaration before calling the action

```
public static void UploadFile()
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

}
```

Comment: As I wrote in the original question: I know I can hardcode the TLS version using ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol, but this goes against Microsofts recommendation and if I hardcode it to TLS 1.2 and 1.3, then whenever TLS 1.4 is used and the customers OS is patched to support it, my application will still use TLS 1.3 which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SystemDefault

**Action Item** : **Testing**

Disable TLS 1.2 on the server

Disable TLS 1.2 also mean server app should work with TLS 1.3 since our app and server supported by OS 2022 and .net framework 4.8 respectively.

I have tried with following scenarios.

Scenario 1 : Registry change

1. ```
   "HKLM:\\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\\" -Name "Enabled" -Value "0" -Type DWord



    2."HKLM:\\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
   ```

   1.2\Server\" -Name "Enabled" -Value "0" -Type DWord

Result : While doing so, server and app not responding in many ways (you can't remote server , Payer, Member URL doesn't respond etc..)

Scenario 2 : Workaround
Introduced new property "DisableByDefault" with value 1 in following path

```
`"HKLM:\\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\\" -Name "DisableByDefault" -Value "1" -Type DWord`
```

`HKLM:\\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server\\" -Name "DisableByDefault" -Value "1" -Type DWord`

3. Restart server.
4. Configure Firefox with below values.
   TLS 1.3 = {min 4 , max 4 , fallback 4} Result : app started working
   TLS 1.2 = {min 3 , max 3 , fallback 3} Result : app stopped working

That way we can conclude TLS 1.2 is disabled and TLS 1.3 is enabled.

Above are the scenarios and steps I have followed on disabling TLS 1.2 and enabling TLS 1.3.

Comment: As I wrote in the comment you replied to: The users who have had issues with it using older TLS versions has been able to resolve it by making registry changes, but telling users to reconfigure settings in Windows registry is a bit risky.

Comment: No registery change is required, mention steps is for testing or we can ask once your change done how we can test? So disable server with lower version